# Details about Azure Media key delivery service?

Tags: azure, azure-media-services

The Azure documentation [Protect your content with Media Services dynamic encryption](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/content-protection-overview) mentions a ***Media Services key delivery service***, which creates *Content Keys* for secure access and can be replaced by a custom service.

> In Media Services v3, a content key is associated with Streaming
> Locator (see this example). If using the Media Services key delivery
> service, you can let Azure Media Services generate the content key for
> you. The content key should be generated yourself if you're using you
> own key delivery service, or if you need to handle a high availability
> scenario where you need to have the same content key in two data
> centers.

I couldn't find any details about the *Media Services key delivery service* itself or about replacing it with a custom implementation.

Where can I find more details about the *Media Services key delivery service*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Key Delivery service is an integrated part of the Media Services dynamic encryption service.

There are two extensibility points. You can plug in a custom Secure Token Service (STS) for token authentication, per the same document that you linked to. You can also provide a content key if you are using your own key delivery service. That is outlined in the section on custom key and license acquisition URL support:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/content-protection-overview#custom-key-and-license-acquisition-url

The two replaceable fields in the templates are there so that you can share your streaming policy across many assets instead of creating a streaming policy per asset.

I believe we have a sample REST call in the Open API documentation for creating a Streaming Policy here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/media/streamingpolicies/create#creates-a-streaming-policy-with-secure-streaming

Comment: Thanks. I've one question about returned content key of the managed service - is the the value fix or does it change over time / per request?

Comment: Take a look at the create Streaming Locator calls. You can override the Content Keys per streaming Locator and reference a labeled in the streaming Policy that contains the DRM templates and encryption settings.

Comment: Try to use very few streaming policies as a best practice.

Comment: Does your comments mean, it creates one fixed content key per streaming policy? Is there a way, to send request to managed service directly (similar to `customKeyAcquisitionUrlTemplate`)? Then I could play around to answer my questions. :)